# Zariski-density is preserved under polynomial map

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

I attempted to do exercise 19 on page 8 of [this paper](http://jones.math.unibas.ch/~kraft/Papers/KP-Primer.pdf). It says:

> **Problem**: Let $\varphi:W\to V$ be a polynomial map of finite-dimensional vector spaces. Let $X\subset Y\subset W$ with $X$ Zariski-dense in $Y$ (i.e. if a function vanishes on $X$, it also vanishes on $Y$). Show that $\varphi(X)$ is Zariski-dense in $\varphi(Y)$.

I tried my luck at it and would appreciate a criticism of my proof:

I use the following

> **Lemma**: Let $\varphi:W\to V$ be a polynomial map of finite-dimensional vector spaces. Then the corresponding algebra homomorphism Let $\varphi^*:K[V]\to K[W],f\mapsto f\circ\varphi$ is injective if and only if $\varphi(W)$ is Zariski-dense in $V$.

Proof: see my [earlier post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/798257/comorphism-of-a-polynomial-map).

**Proof of problem**: Let $\varphi_1^*:K[\varphi(Y)]\to K[X],\varphi_2^*:K[\varphi(Y)]\to K[Y]$ be the associated algebra homomorphism of $\varphi$ restricted to $X$ resp. $Y$. By the lemma it suffices to show that $\varphi_1^*$ is injective. Let $f\in\mathrm{ker}(\varphi_1^*)$, that is  $f=0$ on $\varphi(X)$. But clearly $f\in\mathrm{ker}(\varphi_2^*)$ since $X$ Zariski-dense in $Y$. But $\varphi_2^*$ is injective since $\varphi(Y)$ is Zariski-dense in $\varphi(Y)$, thus $f=0$ on $\varphi(Y)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the OP:

Let φ∗1:K[φ(Y)]→K[X],φ∗2:K[φ(Y)]→K[Y] be the associated algebra homomorphism of φ restricted to X resp. Y. By the lemma it suffices to show that φ∗1 is injective. Let f∈ker(φ∗1), that is f=0 on φ(X). But clearly f∈ker(φ∗2) since X Zariski-dense in Y. But φ∗2 is injective since φ(Y) is Zariski-dense in φ(Y), thus f=0 on φ(Y).